# how can I get one document in mongoose?(don't use aggregate)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to return one index's object of the array,
but when I query, It returns to me that all of the documents.

This is my Schema(userTb)

```
const userTbSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  userId: String,
  folders: [
    {
      folderTitle: String,
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is the result of the query of my Schema(userTb).

```
{
    "_id": "5fc4c13f32ab3174acb08540",
    "userId": "go05111",
    "folders": [
        {
            "_id": "5fb7b0473fddab615456b166",
            "folderTitle": "first-go"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fb7b0473fddab615456b16b",
            "folderTitle": "second-go"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the only { "folderTitle" : "first-go" } folder's object, like...

```
{
    "_id": "5fb7b0473fddab615456b166",
    "folderTitle": "first-go"
}
```

so I query like this

```
router.get('/folder/:folderId', (req, res, next) => {
    UserTb.find({ folders : { "$elemMatch" : { _id : req.params.folderId} } })
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        res.status(200).json({
            docs
        }); 
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

but the result is nothing changed.

I tried a few different ways, but it didn't work out.

how can I fix it in mongoose(don't use aggregate)?

would you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without aggregation, the only thing you can do is using `$elemMatch` into projection find like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "folders.folderTitle": "first-go"
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "folders": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "folderTitle": "first-go"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_xa7vtgDk5G)

The output is only the folder/s whose name match with `first-go`.

Note that you get all values because you are using `$elemMatch` into query. According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) find gets two parameters: Query and projection.

Query is to filter the elements you want to get, so if you do only something like:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "folders._id": "5fb7b0473fddab615456b166"
})
```

It will return the **entire** object where this filter match. Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/90L5uy6d7dt).
Note that only the object where exists one `folder` object with the given `_id` is returned. But is not returned the object into the array, the returned is the entire object.

So, you need to set your query and after that the projection using `$eleMatch`.

You can use an empty object `{}` or a find to filter and get first the document anda later the specific array object.

So the query has to do something like:

```
db.collection.find(
{
  /* First find the documents whose match this filter.
     Here you will get the entire document, not only the 
     object into the array you want*/
},
{
 /* Second filter the documents and get the value you want.
    In this case folderTitle = first-go*/
})
```

And, that's true the output is not exactly what you want, this is the `folders` field only with values whose `match` the `$elemMatch` criteria. But using only `find` is the best approach I think.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can fix my problem with your help.
Thank you so much :D